# Calling object key using data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

Is there a better way to do this:

HTML

```
<textarea name="footer_content" id="footer_content" class="form-control" data-editor="simple"></textarea>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
var summernote_config = {
    'simple': {
        height: 100
    },
    'full': {
        height: 200,
        styleTags: ['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']
    }
};
$('[data-editor]').each(function () {
    $(this).summernote(eval('summernote_config.' + $(this).data('editor')));
});
```

Notice how I'm grabbing the `summernote_config` value by using the `data-editor` attribute via `eval`?

I'm thinking eval might not be the safest option here.

Comment: bracket notation, no need for eval....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the property value into a variable, and then select the property using bracket notation (lets you use dynamic property names) rather than dot notation:

```
$('[data-editor]').each(() => {
  const configProp = $(this).data('editor');
  const configVal = summernote_config[configProp];
  $(this).summernote(configVal);
});
```

Or, to be more concise:

```
$('[data-editor]').each(() => {
  $(this).summernote(summernote_config[$(this).data('editor')]);
});
```